# Get the element calling a function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have two JQuery elements like `$("myDiv1")` and `$("myDiv2")` and I defined a proto for it called `SetText()` ,,
In `SetText` Implementation, How can I know that `myDiv1` is the one who called it if I did `$("myDiv1").SetText()` ?
Thank you,

Comment: Besides your concern, I think you should use `#` for `id` selection, like `$("#myDiv1")`

Comment: @WaldirJ.PereiraJunior of-course this is not what I'm talking about. and this is definitely not my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `this`:

- Within your plugin code, it will refer to the jQuery object your plugin was called on
- Within event handlers and such, it refers to the DOM element

Quick example of a simple plugin with options and a couple of methods:

```js
// Our "nifty" plugin.
// Note this is an ES5 and earlier example, no ES2015+ features used.
(function($) {
  // Convenient access to Array#slice
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
  
  // Our event namespace
  var eventNS = ".nifty";
  
  // Our data name for options
  var optionsName = "options.nifty";
  
  // Some default options
  var niftyDefaults = {
    color: "green",
    text: "default text"
  };
  
  // Our methods
  var methods = {
    init: nifty$init,
    destroy: nifty$destroy,
    options: nifty$options,
    settext: nifty$settext
  };
  
  // Main plugin function
  $.fn.nifty = function(options) {
    // Note that here, `this` is the jQuery object our plugin was called on.
    var method, args;
    
    // Determine the method to call and arguments to it
    if (typeof options === "string") {
      // Method call
      method = options;
      args = slice.call(arguments, 1); // 1 = skip the method name
    } else {
      // Init
      method = "init";
      args = slice.call(arguments, 0); // 0 = copy all
    }
    
    // Call the method, return the result
    return methods[method].apply(this, args);
  };
  
  // Because of the way we call them, `this` in all of our methods below
  // is the jQuery object we were called on
  
  // Init
  function nifty$init(options) {
    // Initialize each element individually
    this.each(function() {
      // Note that here, `this` is the DOM element for this iteration of
      // the `each` loop. Save the options; each element gets its own copy.
      $(this).data(optionsName, $.extend({}, niftyDefaults, options));
      // If we had other per-element init, we'd do it here.
    });
    
    // Let's have our "nifty" set up an event handler when initialized.
    // We do it here because we don't need a separate handler for each
    // individual element.
    this.on("click.nifty", function() {
      // Resond by setting the color according to this specific
      // element's options.
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css("color", $this.data(optionsName).color);
    });
    
    // The main init of a plugin should almost always return `this`
    // for chaining
    return this;
  }

  // Plugins should always have a "destroy" method that undoes what they do
  // in init. It should handle it gracefully if init hasn't been called on
  // the elements.
  function nifty$destroy() {
    // Remove our event handler
    this.off("click" + eventNS);

    // Remove the event data
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).removeData(optionsName);
    });
  }
  
  // Our "options" method
  function nifty$options(newOptions) {
    // For each element in the matched set, update the options.
    // Note how we're returning the return value from `this.each`, which is
    // `this`. A method should always return `this` unless it has a good
    // reason for doing something else.
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var opts = $this.data(optionsName);
      checkForInit("options", opts);
      $this.data(optionsName, $.extend({}, opts, newOptions));
    });
  }

  // Our "settext" method
  function nifty$settext() {
    // Set the text on each matched element individually, according to its
    // options.
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var opts = $this.data(optionsName);
      checkForInit("settext", opts);
      $this.text(opts.text);
    });
  }

  // Worker function, throws exception if a method is called on an
  // un-initialized element.
  function checkForInit(method, opts) {
    if (typeof opts === "undefined") {
      throw new Error(method + " cannot be called until `nifty` has been initialized on the element");
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

// Using it -- init
$(".foo").nifty({color: "blue"});
$(".bar").nifty({text: "bar text"});

// Calling methods - give different texts to each of the foos, override
// the color we use on the last one
$(".foo")
  .first()
  .nifty("options", {text: "I'm the first foo"})
  .end()
  .last()
  .nifty("options", {text: "I'm the last foo", color: "orange"});
         
// Call "settext" on all the foos and bars
$(".foo, .bar").nifty("settext");

// Destroy "nifty" on bar
$(".bar").nifty("destroy");

// Prove that we did and that methods complain
try {
  $(".bar").nifty("options", {color: "blue"});
  console.log("Shouldn't get here");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Correctly got error: " + e.message);
}
```

```html
<div>Click each of the three divs below.</div>
<div style="padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd">
  <div class="foo">foo1</div>
  <div class="foo">foo2</div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
</div>
<div>Note that clicking the 'bar' element doesn't change its color, because we destroyed the nifty plugin on it after using nifty to set its text</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a working example? Cause this is what I've done so far and `this` always refers to the last defined object

Comment: @JosephKhella: I've added one. :-)

Comment: Crowder ,, I've edited your code to match what I need,, It works now with your example although I still don't know what's wrong with my source code,, but works with yours,,, so this is accepted,, thx man :)  `http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/1497/`

Comment: @JosephKhella: You wouldn't normally add a method there, you'd do it as I've done `nifty` above: `$.fn.nifty = ...` Doing `$(this).init.prototype.settext =` creates a `settext` method for **all** jQuery instances everywhere, but (in your example) it's always hooked up to a function interwoven with the most recent call to the `each` callback in that code, which will create really weird cross-talk between instances.

Comment: @JosephKhella: If you're looking to add further methods, typically that's now how it's done with plugins. You just have one function (`nifty` in my example), and if you want to have methods, you pass them as strings. I'll update the above to show how methods are usually done.

Comment: ,, Yes that would be great and very kind of you,, cause that's exactly what I'm doing now,, I'm making a bootstrap plugin,, and yes As you were saying,,, that's my problem now, the options i'm sending to the plugin in the initialization are being overridden with the latest options call

Comment: @JosephKhella: Updated. :-)

Comment: This is genius :D I would re accept the answer hahaha :D